# How to pass data(Args,parameter,list ..etc) from python2 to python3 in memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Owing to some reason,I must use "win32com" this module to output my Dataframe from another appication (But this module seems to be only in python2).

However , I want to do some calculate in python3 with this Dataframe(output by python2).

How can I send the Dataframe from python2 to python3 in memory? (Except to output the data to the file)

---

Supplementary explanation 1:
My os is Win10 64bit (both contain python2 and python3)
In short , I want to know how can I pass the Data(produced by python2) to python3.

---

Supplementary explanation 2:
I have a A python script and it need to run in python2.
A python script will generated some data(maybe json , dataframe ..)
And then I want pass this data to B python script
B python script must run in python3.

My os is win10 64bits(both have python2 and 3).
I am a new to python , I have tried "out the data to the file ,then B.py read the file". However this I/O way is too slow , so I want pass data in memory , how can I do that?
(My English is not very good, please entertain me )

Comment: What OS are you on? What are the requirements? Why do you need to do this? What have you already tried?

Comment: If you can send arbitrary data via a socket or stream, [`parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_parquet.html) might be the most suited data format

Comment: I just want pass the data from python2 to python3 . I have tried "output the data to file" , but this I/O bound way is too slow .  My os is Win10 64bit (contain python2 and python3).

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a convenient option.

```
import json
```

read the docs for specifics and examples
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Seems like a good idea , however how can I pass "json" from python2 to python3 ?    tks for your reply = )

Comment: json can be used to serialize data which can then be written to a flle.  your other program can then read that file and recreate the object

Comment: I know that . However written to a file is an I/O bound way. (My data is big , so this way will work very slow)Is there anyway that I can pass this data except output the file?